# Can I initialize Typescript field using another field's value

Tags: typescript

Typescript (method1):

```
import { MyService } from './MyService';

export class Foo {
   constructor(private service: MyService) {}
   field1= this.service.getSomeResultWithAComplicatedType()
}
```

Transpiles to:

```
    let Foo = class Foo {
    constructor(service) {
        this.field1 = service.getSomeResultWithAComplicatedType();
    }
};
```

What the documentation seem to recommend (method2):

```
import { MyExtremelyComplicatedType } from './MyExtremelyComplicatedType.ts';
import { MyService } from './MyService';

class Foo {
   field1: MyExtremelyComplicatedType;
   constructor(service: MyService) {
      this.field1 = service.getSomeResultWithAComplicatedType()
   }
}
```

And indeed, both methods yield the same transpiled javascript. BUT, eslint's *no-invalid-this* rule balks at method1. I like it because it avoids importing types that aren't actually needed (the example is simplified here, imagine the same with lots of fields, generics etc...). It also makes refactorings arguably easier: imagine changing getSomeResultWithAComplicatedType to return a different type, you wouldn't need to change Foo at all.

Question: Is initializing fields like method1 a bad thing? If not, then is eslint's *no-invalid-this* wrong to tell me off here, and why wouldn't method1 be the recommended approach for initializing fields from constructor parameters?

Comment: Can you provide an actual, minimal example.

Comment: In method 1, it looks like you are assigning the field with a value, not setting a type. I don't understand why method 1 works at all :P

Comment: Did you mean `field1 = this.service.getSomeResultWithAComplicatedType();` in method 1? In that case, I think it is a great way to write succinct code. We've used it for several years in a large project. The field will have the correct type and assignment will be done in correct order. Perhaps the eslint rule is not made for typescript.

Comment: Oops, my bad. That's what I meant. Updated the question. Thanks

Comment: You might be right here Markus (re rule not being for typescript). I am comforted by the fact someone else uses code like this to initialise fields!